# rpart:confusionMatrix error (regression tree)

Tags: r, decision-tree

I prepare regression tree using rpart library in R! I have 4 dependent vars and three independent predictors. All vars are scale(i.e. metric scale.)

```
mydata="mydata.csv"
library(caret)
library("rpart")
class1=read.csv(mydata,sep=";",dec=",")
# rpart
fit <- rpart(y1+y2+y3+y6~ ., method="anova",data=class1)
set.seed(123)
index <- sample(1:nrow(class1),round(0.75*nrow(class1)))
train <- class1[index,]
str(train)
test <- class1[-index,]
str(test)
fit <- rpart(y1+y2+y3+y6~ ., method="anova",data=train)
predict(fit)
predicted.t=predict(fit)
```

Now i want use `confusionMatrix()` but i got the error

```
> confusionMatrix(predicted.t,test)
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

>

```
 dput(class)
structure(list(x1 = c(215L, 170L, 340L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 300L, 
305L, 345L, 300L, 340L, 220L, 320L, 220L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 215L, 
275L, 255L, 275L, 320L, 345L, 250L, 220L, 250L, 300L, 220L, 215L, 
300L, 255L, 345L, 350L, 305L, 320L, 215L, 215L, 300L, 220L, 255L, 
305L, 320L, 345L, 250L, 305L, 255L, 305L, 305L, 255L, 275L, 320L, 
340L, 250L, 300L, 305L, 320L, 250L, 300L, 215L, 250L, 220L, 220L, 
320L, 300L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 305L, 170L, 220L, 350L, 320L, 215L, 
305L, 255L, 170L, 340L, 300L, 300L, 255L, 300L, 320L, 275L, 275L,
```

If

```
 View(class)
x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  y6
215 15,4    94  90  7   3   54,886501
170 16  85  90  6   4   54,886501
340 12,2    72  70  15  15  54,886501
320 15,1    78  80  12  8   54,886501
320 9,7 77  80  5   15  54,886501
320 11,1    70  90  1   9   54,886501
300 14,6    85  80  14  6   54,886501
305 8,6 74  90  6   4   54,886501
345 15  85  90  5   5   54,886501
300 13,7    85  90  7   3   54,886501
340 14,3    82  80  18  2   54,886501
220 8,6 77  80  15  5   54,886501
320 13,2    73  80  12  8   54,886501
220 8,4 85  90  5   5   54,886501
300 16  85  90  7   3   56,08118233
300 8,4 72  90  7   3   54,886501
300 13,7    77  90  7   3   54,886501
215 15,1    77  90  6   4   56,08118233
275 12,2    94  70  15  15  56,08118233
255 16  85  80  12  8   54,886501
275 11,1    94  80  5   15  54,886501
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: Please note that `class` is a base function in R and your dataset overwrites on the function definition.Also, while using randomized sampling remember to `set.seed(x)` with x as your favourite number to ensure reproducibility of results.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post. Here mydata in .csv format.  [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/ws44ig)

Answer (score 0):

Here there answer

```
u = union(round(predicted.t),test$y6)
t = table(factor(round(predicted.t), u), factor(test$y6, u))
confusionMatrix(t)
```

so matrix works.